# How to assign object's for loop output to a variable

Tags: javascript

While I'm converting the array to object, I found a critical mistake that I can't solve. When we use `map` method to an array, it returns something but with the object, it doesn't return anything.

```
let output = for(var key in taggedOnes) { <- this is not a good approach at all. 
// But I'm looking for similar logic.
      let item = taggedOnes[key];
      ...
      if(id===this.state.selectedClothId) {
        return ( <- I can't return it? :(
          <View
            key={id}
            style={{
              top,
              left,
              height: thumbSize,
              width: thumbSize,
              borderWidth: 2,
              borderColor: 'yellow'
            }}
          />
        );
      } else {
        return (
          <View
            key={id}
            style={{
              top,
              left,
              height: thumbSize,
              width: thumbSize,
              borderWidth: 2,
              borderColor: 'white'
            }}
          />
        );
      }
    }
    return output; <- I want to return whole React Elements in one element like array.
```

Comment: `Object.keys` is a function that returns an array of an object’s keys.

Comment: So how do we assign multiple react native component to a variable, `output`?

Comment: Now I'm very confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Object/keys) to get an array with the keys in your `taggedOnes` object.
Then, you can call [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/map) on this array to browse your array and return another array.

I don't know where do you create your `id` variable, but you can easily adapt the following example:

```
const output = Object.keys(taggedOnes).map(key => {
      const item = taggedOnes[key];

      if (id === this.state.selectedClothId) {
        return (
          <View
            key={id}
            style={{
              top,
              left,
              height: thumbSize,
              width: thumbSize,
              borderWidth: 2,
              borderColor: 'yellow'
            }}
          />
        );
      } else {
        return (
          <View
            key={id}
            style={{
              top,
              left,
              height: thumbSize,
              width: thumbSize,
              borderWidth: 2,
              borderColor: 'white'
            }}
          />
        );
      }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is `Object.keys(taggedOnes).map`. A for loop doesn't return anything it just loops over the values, a return statement inside a for loop will return the current function.

Map, on the other hand, transforms each element of the array using the provided function, in your case it is/was transforming it to a list of react components.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.keys(taggedOnes).map` to convert the `taggedOnes` object to an array of its transformed values.

```
let output = Object.keys(taggedOnes).map(key => {
  let item = taggedOnes[key];
  ...
  if (id===this.state.selectedClothId) {
    return ...
  } else {
    return ...
  }
});
```